# Are unused function arguments always instantiated?

Tags: c++

Given a function with an unused (and unnamed) argument:

```
template <typename T> void f(T&&) { /* do something, without using T */ }

int main() 
{
    std::mutex m;
    f(std::lock_guard<std::mutex> { m });
}
```

Is the argument guaranteed to be instantiated, or is the compiler allowed to optimize it away?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The constructor may have side-effects.

Comment: @user5434231: Add a side effect to your example code. If there are no side effects, then the answer becomes too trivial, because the as-if rule allows all optimisations.

Comment: I've added an example with `std::lock_guard`, which locks a mutex and unlocks it on destruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [class.temp]:

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that has a non-trivial constructor (12.1, 12.8), **it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object.**

The standard also provides an out in [intro.execution]:

> Rather, conforming
>   implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained
>   below.<sup>5</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>5</sup>This provision is sometimes called the “as-if” rule, because an implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this
>   International Standard as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed, as far as can be determined from the
>   observable behavior of the program. For instance, an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression **if it can
>   deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects affecting the observable behavior of the program are produced**.

Certainly, acquiring a lock qualifies as a side effect affecting observable behavior, so yes, the argument is guaranteed to be instantiated since it has a non-trivial constructor with observable side-effects.

Comment: Except there's the as-if rule.